# log4j no appender could be found for logger configured in standalone.xml

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x

I'm using jboss as 7 in standalone mode. I'm using spring in my app, when I ran my app I get the following error in the server log:

```
17:40:19,669 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
17:40:19,671 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

So I configured jboss as by adding the logger as follow:

```
        <logger category="org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
                <handler name="TESTFILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

The handler CONSOLE is defined as follow:

```
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
```

But even after doing that I keep receiving the same error, why?

### Solution:

The missing part was to indicate that the application should use the subsystem `logging` of jboss as (log4j) located in its directory `modules` more precisely in `org/apache/log4j`. This is done by adding the file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to WEB-INF containing the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Do messages seem to be getting logged?

Comment: No I get the same errors.

Comment: So you see the error, but no logged messages correct?

Comment: Yes I see the error, but no logged messages.

Comment: Spring must be attempting to configure log4j then. You're probably best to exclude the server version of log4j, package your own and use a log4j configuration. I don't know enough about how Spring works, but that is my best guess.

Comment: I can do it as you said (use my own log4j configuration), I already did. But I am looking for how to configure it using jboss as.

Comment: I think the issue is Spring is trying to configure logging. There might be a way to turn that off, but I just don't know much about Spring.

Answer (score 0):

yo have to define an appender in your config:

```
<appender name="springFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../logs/spring.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />

    </layout>
</appender>
```

then reference it from the logger :

```
<logger name="org.springframework.beans" additivity="true">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="springFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

this config would log everything from Spring Beans module with a threshold of INFO in a file ../logs/spring.log

EDIT:  I see, you are using log4J with JBOSS!

then you should define the handler (like the appender in my example).

Something similar to this:

```
 <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="false"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Comment: The appender is the same as the handler in the standalone.xml configuration file.

Comment: see my edit.  you should define your handlers to something similar. Hope it solve your problem.  Regards

Comment: The handlers are already defined, take as example the CONSOLE handler.